# Catch Vlookup 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Vlookup to find some taxes in the "Database" (DB_SHEET). When my name doesn't exist in my DBs i got Error '1004' in VlookUp.

Why 'On Error GoTo Err1' doesn't catch the error?

My Code:

```
Dim tax1 as Double, tax2 as Double, name as String

On Error GoTo Err1
While Cells(rowIndex, 1) <> ""
    name = Cells(rowIndex, 4)
    fin = Cells(rowIndex, 5) * Cells(rowIndex, 6)
    tax1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets(DB_SHEET).Range("D:G"), 3, False)
    tax2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets(DB_SHEET).Range("K:P"), 2, False)

    Cells(rowIndex, 8) = (fin * tax1) - (fin * tax2)
Err1:
    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
Wend
On Error Goto 0
```

I already know a code that works but i want to understand why i can't do "WorksheetFunction" and catch error using "On Error" .

Other version that works:

```
Dim tax1 as Variant, tax2 as Variant, name as String

While Cells(rowIndex, 1) <> ""
    name = Cells(rowIndex, 4)
    fin = Cells(rowIndex, 5) * Cells(rowIndex, 6)
    tax1 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets(DB_SHEET).Range("D:G"), 3, False)
    tax2 = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name, Sheets(DB_SHEET).Range("K:P"), 2, False)

    If Not IsError(tax1) And not IsError(tax2) Then
         Cells(rowIndex, 8) = (fin * tax1) - (fin * tax2)
    End if

    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
Wend
```

**Edit (After : K_B answer)**

1) If i use Application.Vlookup(...) insead of WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(...) i got "Error 13".

Comment: I don't think you can use an error handler in a loop like that.  Try moving it outside of the loop then add a Resume Next after incrementing the row number.

Comment: Yes I can. And I don't want to use "Resume Next", in this code i prefer to use "On erro goto Label:"

Comment: Resume Next goes after your error label.  I wasn't suggesting you use "On Error Resume Next"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the difference between an Excel error and a VB error. Your VLookup casts an Excel error but the VB code works fine (the variant will just contain the error code now). Where if you would do 1/0 in your VBA you would get a VB error that will be captured with the `On Error GoTo ...`

You already found the solution yourself to capture the Excel error by checking if the value of the expressions are errors with the `IsError()` function, so I cant fill you in there!

Now supposing that `tax1` and `tax2` are decimal numbers normally you could change the `Dim`  for these 2 variables to reflect this and dimension them as `Single` in stead of as `Variant`. NOW you will get a VB error when your VLookup fails as the error cannot be put in the `Single` and THAT FAIL you can capture with an `On Error GoTo ...`

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply. But if i change from "code 2" my tax1 and tax2 to Single i got the same error. And even if i change WorksheetFunction to Application function i got 'Error 13' instead of 'Error 1004'.

Comment: The main point to note here i think is that `Application.Worksheetfunction.VLookup()` will throw an error (which must be caught using an error handler) if the search value isn't found (assuming the last argument is FALSE).  `Application.VLookup()` will not _throw_ an error, but will instead _return_ an error, which as you note you can test with `IsError()`.

Comment: I understand what you told about Vlookup(), but my question was not that. I was surprised that Vlookup() return the value expected (string, int, double ...) or an Error. So, even if i know that the return a double i can't define it as a double because the function could return an error.

Comment: You can define you local variables as double but need to set up a catch and/or check for the error before you assign it to your local variable. In case of such error of course you have to decide yourself what you want the script to do next (inform the user/take a default value/follow an alternative piece of code/do nothing).